# Data is not returned for every URL input

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am not getting the labels and other properties on all the URL's when using the Google Vision API. It randomly gives this error on some URL.

> {'responses': [{'error': {'code': 7, 'message': "We're not allowed to access the URL on your behalf. Please download the content and pass it in."}}]}

As in, on some runs I don't see this error on the URL and get data, and on the other runs I see the error.

Comment: I cannot download the content as I am running everything on a server

Comment: I have the same issue here, Dec 2018. I'm wondering if you have to authorize the domain somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access an image on someone else's server? It's possible that they're throttling your access, so that the Vision API can't access the image each time. You may have to slow down your requests.